# How can I run multi-line commands inside the spinnaker-spinnaker-halyard-0

Tags: bash, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I am writing a bash file where I wrote some scripts to install the spinnaker in Kubernetes cluster (minikube) everything is working fine, the spinnaker is installed now but when I come inside the halyard and want to run few scripts from my bash file then it is coming inside my halyard container but not executing the next commands because I don't know how to run the multiple commands under it. I tried \ and && as well but not working.
These are my commands

```
kubectl exec --namespace spinnaker -it spinnaker-spinnaker-halyard-0 bash 
hal config features edit --artifacts true 
hal config artifact github enable 
GITHUB_ACCOUNT_NAME=github_user 
hal config artifact github account add ${GITHUB_ACCOUNT_NAME} \
  --token
hal deploy apply
```

if I try `kubectl exec --namespace spinnaker -it spinnaker-spinnaker-halyard-0 bash \` then it is running the next command (`hal config features edit --artifacts true` ) but it is showing error "--unknown flag --artifacts".

NOTE: If I run these command manually in the CLI then everything works fine but I want to run these commands from my bash file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the commands that you want to run are not stored in a file in the container. If you add these commands to a script file(e.g. `config-halyard.sh`), and mount a persistent volume to the Halyard container(containing this script), you should be able to execute it from outside the container with this command:

```
kubectl exec --namespace spinnaker -it spinnaker-spinnaker-halyard-0 /bin/bash config-halyard.sh
```

That is assuming that the script would be in the container's root directory